# Call jQuery append method to content within AngularJS controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have got a page with with dynamic dialog and would like to add some content into it from angularJS controller.

The html code is:

```
 <ons-template id="calendar.html">
  <ons-dialog style="height: 250px;" var="naviDialog" cancelable  ng-controller="datesController">
    <ons-navigator var="myNav">
      <div id="sevenDays" style="text-align: center"></div>
    </ons-navigator>
  </ons-dialog>
</ons-template>
```

And controller looks like:

```
module.controller('datesController', function($scope) {
      $scope.addDates = function () {
         for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
          $("#sevenDays").append("<div id='day" + i + "'>" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear() + "</div>");
        }
        $("#day0").replaceWith("<div id='day0' class='current'>today</div>");
        $("#day1").replaceWith("<div id='day1'>tomorrow</div>");
      };
      $scope.addDates();
    });
```

But jQuery doesn't append content into #datesController

Would anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Instead of doing it via jQuery, why don't you include the HTML in the `<div id="sevenDays" style="text-align: center"></div>`, run a `ng-repeat` in it, and update the model in the `controller`.

Comment: Hi @Shashank can you show me an example? many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please try to update the DOM per $scope.$apply() after you manipulate him.

Comment: Thank you @bgeissler can you show me an example how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery with AngularJs is not an good practice.Both will use own DOM instance better try like this if you want append any Div

var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
myEl.prepend('your html
');

else
write your directives

Answer (score 0):

I have done a quick setTimeout trick to my code and it works fine now:

```
 module.controller('datesController', function($scope) {
      $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
         for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
          $("#sevenDays .list").append("<ons-list-item modifier='tappable' id='day" + i + "'>" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear() + "</ons-list-item>");
        }
        $("#day0").replaceWith("<ons-list-item modifier='tappable' id='day0' class='current'>today</ons-list-item>");
        $("#day1").replaceWith("<ons-list-item modifier='tappable' id='day1'>tomorrow</ons-list-item>");
      }, 100);
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/9eoyv9ga/) link in jsfiddle that shows the working example. Below is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div id="sevenDays" ng-controller="datesController">
    <div id="day{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="item in dateList">
        {{$index + 1}}) 
        <span ng-if="$index == 0">today</span>
        <span ng-if="$index == 1">tomorrow</span>
        <span ng-if="(($index != 0) && ($index != 1))">{{item.date}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('datesController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.dateList = [];
    $scope.addDates = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
            $scope.dateList.push({ 'date': ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear() });
        }
    };
    $scope.addDates();
});
```